# how to add Sandbox entitlements to cocoa bundle project

Tags: xcode, npapi, sandbox

Does anyone know how to add sandbox entitlements to special xcode project like cocoa bundle project?

I have a Safari plugin under development, which is created in xcode with bundle project type. The compiled code works well on Snow Leopard while it fails on Lion. By debugging i found that the socket can not be opened! Google tells me that application on Lion shall have Sandbox entitlements and have the networking related keys set to YES to get network accessibility.

It is pretty easy for cocoa application but turns out to be blocking me for the plugin since it is not an application but a bundle project!

Appreciate it if anyone can share your experience.

Comment: Hmm... that is definitely a concerning report. The general rule of thumb for plugins is always that you have only the privileges or rights that your parent process has and you have no control over what those are.

Comment: If you don't get it working, maybe you can delegate the work to a privileged background helper process?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that the socket connection failure has nothing to do with Sandbox entitlements. It is caused by invalid host address. NPAPI passed in the string as bytes. It does not have NULL terminator and you should use memcpy with UTF8Length to copy the data. I was using strcpy to get the host address, which produces invalid value.